How to narrow hotel map down to Old Town of Cologne, Germany
I am tasked to find overnight accommodations in the Old town of Cologne Germany.  I can summon a map of hotels in the surrounding areas:

How can I reduce the number options so that they are only in the old part of town?  I know how to use the Google maps to scroll / zoom: where are the limits of the old town?
I've never been to Cologne and hope that the experience of others will prevail.

Have you tried to limit the distance from the town center?

Can't you just zoom in on that map?

This map shows what they consider to be the old town (Altstadt). Left bank of the Rhine, limited by the "Ring" and the railway tracks. Some would probably consider the "old town" to be every more restricted, but there doesn't seem to be really much of anything old left in Cologne other than a few churches (including the Cathedral), so don't expect much of "old town" feel, more of "city centre" (I'm not familiar with the city but that's what it looks like on Google Maps).

Look for a Cathedral and in Europe that will be the general area of the old city. Kölner Dom

Note: it depends on what do you mean with "old town". What do you want to do in Cologne? So restrict depending on such requirements. (European cities are old, some for some definition of old, the old city is very large. For tourist (and base), stay near main train station (and so cathedral and pedestrian zone). Or other possibility is near U-Bahn (tube), so that you can reach station quickly. For business, prefer the quartier where you need to go. For expo: where you find something (all hotels may be very busy): I think you may need to tell us more about purpose for targeted tips.

Depends on the search tool you are using but most that I use (Booking, Expedia, Google Maps, Tripadvisor) have a zoom feature where you can zoom in and move the search area around. Sometimes there is a check box to "update search when I move/zoom). But in Google Maps its straightforward. You can even see the plus/minus sign on the picture you posted. To speed things up, open Google Maps and search for "hotels in Cologne".
The picture below shows what most people would consider the "old town". It's on the west side of the river and roughly surrounded by the B9 and the B55. Keep in mind that Cologne was heavily damaged in World War II so old stuff and post-war architecture are well mixed.


I suppose OP's main question really is: what are the limits of the "Old Town"?

@jcaron.  Yes, I do not know the "limits"

It's worth noting that the yellowish parts of the map are what Google consider to be areas with shop and/or bars, restaurants.

@gatorback: I added the info. Due to the heavy bombings Cologne doesn't have a real "old town" any more like many other German cities, so it depends a bit on your definition. The most touristy places are close to the river and around the Cathedral.

You can also go on Google maps with satellite and 3d buildings on or use Streetview to look at the surroundings. As a general piece of advice, generally in German cities the Cathedral and Rathaus are in the old town. But as Hilmar said, Cologne's old town stopped existing in the 1940s.

@gatorback That might be more of a question as to why you specifically want the "old town". European city centers tend to be small (and well connected with transit). Arbitrary lines on the pavement can rule out good options which are a reasonable & pleasant walk/tram ride from where you actually want to be. (And some hotels can be inside the "official" district, but not actually be the "old town" feel you're actually looking for.)
